# Hierarchy Query with join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with user id's and another table with hierarchy elements.  The table with the user id has a unique key to the table that has the hierarchy elements. What I'm trying to accomplish is to display every element of the 
hierarchy table by user. The problem is that I have hierarchy nodes that I need to traverse and display. Below is an example of the tables that I'm using and the data that I'm using.

```
create table fsecure(
userid varchar(100),
f_element varchar(6)
);

REM INSERTING into FSECURE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into FSECURE (USERID,F_ELEMENT) values ('FFA','140');
Insert into FSECURE (USERID,F_ELEMENT) values ('FFA','280');
Insert into FSECURE (USERID,F_ELEMENT) values ('GGA','202118');
Insert into FSECURE (USERID,F_ELEMENT) values ('GGA','140');
Insert into FSECURE (USERID,F_ELEMENT) values ('RFA','202116');



CREATE TABLE "FVAL" 
   ( "FUND" VARCHAR2(6 ), 
     "FUND_PRED" VARCHAR2(6)
   ) 

REM INSERTING into FVAL
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('140',null);
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('280',null);
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('2000','140');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('20001','2000');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('20002','2000');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('20003','2000');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('202118','2000');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('2800','280');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('280001','2800');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('280002','2800');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('280003','2800');
Insert into FVAL (FUND,FUND_PRED) values ('280004','2800');
```

here is a query that works for when I'm doing this for you just one user.

```
  SELECT      F.FUND
     FROM        FVAL F
     CONNECT BY PRIOR F.FUND    =   F.FUND_PRED
     START WITH  F.FUND  IN ( SELECT F_ELEMENT  FROM FSECURE WHERE USERID = 'FFA' );
```

I would like to make this generic enough to display the element with every user from fsecure.

expected output (**Note: I'm only showing one user but I would like to do this for every user on table fsecure**)

```
"FUND"  "'FFA'"
"140"   "FFA"
"2000"  "FFA"
"20001" "FFA"
"20002" "FFA"
"20003" "FFA"
"202118"    "FFA"
"280"   "FFA"
"2800"  "FFA"
"280001"    "FFA"
"280002"    "FFA"
"280003"    "FFA"
"280004"    "FFA"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for providing the DDL statements up front! *{:-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're after:

```
SELECT     fv.fund,
           connect_by_root(fs.userid) userid
FROM       fval fv
           FULL OUTER JOIN fsecure fs ON (fs.f_element = fv.fund) -- maybe left outer join?
CONNECT BY PRIOR fv.fund = fv.fund_pred
START WITH fs.userid IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY   connect_by_root(fs.userid),
           connect_by_root(fs.f_element),
           LEVEL,
           fv.fund;

FUND   USERID
------ ------
140    FFA
2000   FFA
20001  FFA
20002  FFA
20003  FFA
202118 FFA
280    FFA
2800   FFA
280001 FFA
280002 FFA
280003 FFA
280004 FFA
140    GGA
2000   GGA
20001  GGA
20002  GGA
20003  GGA
202118 GGA
202118 GGA
       RFA
```

N.B. I wasn't sure if you wanted the RFA userid to be displayed in the output, since it doesn't have a corresponding fund in the fval table. If you don't want the RFA userid in the output then simply convert the full outer join into a left outer join instead.

Comment: lol - gotta love these folks who post their questions everywhere. I offered essentially the same solution on OTN (except that I did the hierarchical query first and only then joined - the benefit, I think, is that we don't shuffle as much data around during the hierarchical part). I also guessed inner join but offered left outer join as an alternative depending on requirement. (Full didn't cross my mind.) Cheers!

Comment: @mathguy so I'm guessing your answer was similar to Michael's? Regardless of where the OP cross posted this to, I'm in awe that we had DDL statements without needing to ask!

Comment: The solution is indeed very similar to Michael's. Re: statements to recreate the data, people on OTN have been more successful at getting that from more posters. The format is more conducive to that, too - SO is a bit cramped. And there are way more people on SO who are willing to post answers without testing them, too. Not quite as many on OTN.

Comment: I think I figured out the benefit of doing the join first - it avoids reading the FSECURE table twice (once in the subquery to determine what to START the hierarchical query WITH and then again for the join). I hope I'll remember next time!   :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I understand you may use something like :

```
SELECT s.USERID,  hier_f.FUND
   FROM FSECURE s 
   JOIN (  SELECT  F.FUND, connect_by_root(F.FUND) as root_fund
     FROM    FVAL F
     CONNECT BY PRIOR F.FUND    =   F.FUND_PRED
     START WITH  F.FUND  IN ( SELECT F_ELEMENT  FROM FSECURE)) hier_f 
   on s.F_ELEMENT =  hier_f.root_fund
```